# Connect with go code from Kubernetes to external Kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

An operator I'm building needs to talk to other Kubernetes clusters, are there any best practices on how to do that from within the operator that runs on Kubernetes?

Using `k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd` package I can call `BuildConfigFromFlags` method passing `masterURL` and kubeconfig location. This works fine from outside Kubernetes, but within Kubernetes, can any assumptions be made about kubeconfig location? Or should some other API be used?

As a side note: I'm using `controller-runtime`'s `Client` API for talking to Kubernetes.

Comment: Question: Are these two clusters on GKE or are they managed on other environments by you manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's quite easy to do, just call the following with the master URL and the token to access it:

```
cfg, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags(os.Getenv("MASTERURL"), os.Getenv("KUBECONFIG"))
cfg.BearerToken = os.Getenv("BEARERTOKEN")
```

It might also require:

```
cfg.Insecure = true
```

Answer (score 2):

A kubernetes operator is, in the end, a pod running inside of Kubernetes. Nicola Ben`s answer is the way to go if you want to access the current K8S cluster's API.

However, you're saying your operator "needs to talk to **other** Kubernetes clusters" (my emphasis), and that it works locally.

Then, one simple approach is to create a `ConfigMap` containing the `kubeconfig` file, and mount that to a known location in the operator pod. Then you can simply use that the same way you do it locally.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running inside a Kubernetes pod and need to talk to a different Kubernetes cluster. Not sure your solution works because an operator does not have access in advance to the kubeconfig file.

Comment: An operator is nothing special, its a just a pod (Deployment) that accesses the k8s api. Of course it is your responsibility to mount a Kubeconfig file with the correct configuration that the Pod ("operator") can then open and use.

Comment: This. It's exactly how we do it here, we have multiple Kubernetes clusters, and one of them runs a nightly backup job for some services on the other clusters. kubeconfig in a configmap, plus some bash running kubectl commands.

Answer (score 1):

From "Programming Kubernetes", ed. Oreilly (which I suggest as reading):

"When running a binary inside of a pod in a cluster, the kubelet will automatically mount a service account into the container at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount. It replaces the kubeconfig file just mentioned and can easily be turned into a rest.Config via the rest.InClusterConfig() method."

Required config is taken with this line:

```
cfg, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
```

Take a look at the code here:

https://github.com/programming-kubernetes/cnat/blob/master/cnat-client-go/main.go

Comment: Hmmm, not sure this works either. I can't see how you can take rest.Client and get a kubeconfig file out of it, or create a `k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd/api.Config` instance to be able to use the `clientcmd` package to talk to a remote Kubernetes.

Comment: Although correct, this is not the answer to the question posed. The question is about accessing the API of a *different* k8s cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Are these two clusters on GKE or are they managed on other environments by you manually?

A Kubernetes service is basically a collection of pods which can be your controller.

One way to accomplish this is by exposing your service to outside the cluster. On GKE you can do this by using an ILB, ILB will help you expose the service to other k8s clusters you might want to connect to in the same VPC.
But if the other services you need to connect to are in some other VPC you should either:

1. Connect via public internet with an intermediate load balancer in
   the middle. Not recommended for sensitive traffic. ~or~
2. Peer the two VPCs and again use some sort of load balancer that can connect the two k8s clusters. (NGINX might work here but depends on what you're doing)

Does this help?